# How to use toAbsolutePath and Paths.get from java.nio with lower API

Tags: android, file, kotlin, path, android-api-levels

I have an app that needs to send multiple image attachments in an email. To send the images, I need an absolute path. For this, I use functions `.toAbsolutePath` and `Paths.get` from `java.nio`. Both of these functions only work with `API 26` and higher. They seem to me like really basic functions, so I don't know why they don't support lower APIs. Is there any way to make them work with lower `APIs`?

```
realPath1 = Paths.get("storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.abbmalfunctionreport/cache/$image1").toAbsolutePath()
```

Comment: If you put a `/` on the front of the value you are passing to `Paths.get()`, that *is* an absolute path.

Comment: Unfortunately, `Paths.get()`has minimal API 26 as well.

Comment: No, my point is that *you already have the absolute path*, and so `Paths.get()` is unnecessary.

Comment: True. `/storage/emulated/0/.../` is absolute.

Comment: Oh, okay. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`File.getAbsolutePath()` is available since API-1.

You should probably use `Environment` class also, see [How to get absolute path of Internal Storage in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46610819/how-to-get-absolute-path-of-internal-storage-in-android)

Comment: File.getAbsolutePath() is not working for me. I can't explain why, but it is stuck at sending the email. I think the output is different than from the code before.

Comment: What you pass to `Paths.get()` is already hard-coded absolute. Use `Environment` and `File.getAbsolutePath()` to get what you want. I works :)